# How to fix 'undefined reference to _gfortran_concat_string and to _gfortran_etime when building MXNET?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, mxnet, openblas

I am trying to build MXNET from this repo https://github.com/mahyarnajibi/SNIPER/tree/cvpr3k. I have cuda, cudnn, and openblas installed. I build the code with the following command: `make  -j 8 USE_CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda`

The error message is as follows:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
/usr/local/liblibopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_etime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:454: recipe for target 'bin/im2rec' failed
make: *** [bin/im2rec] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

My config.mk file has these settings for some relevant (i think) variables:

```
ADD_LDFLAGS=
ADD_CFLAGS=
USE_CUDA=1
USE_CUDNN=1
USE_OPENCV=1
USE_BLAS=openblas
USE_LAPACK=1
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. We need the complete output, not just the error message. The last command the `make` issued is the most important.

Comment: It seems a apart of Openblas was built with gfortran.  The names of a few of the Makefile variable suggest you're trying to use CUDA.  What compilers are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I was able to fix the problem by adding ```-lgfortran``` to ```ADD_LFLAGS```.

Comment: I had a similar problem when trying to use `lapack` library. Linking with `gfortran` library solved my problem, HOWEVER, make sure to place `gfortran` last in the list of linked libraries because the ordering matters. This was the tail of my command line: `-lm -llapacke -llapack -lrefblas -lgfortran`. When `-lgfortran` was first, linker gave me error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linker error. As the author mentioned, this error can be solved by specifying gfortran in the LDFLAGS. Modify your `config.mk` to have:

```
ADD_LDFLAGS=-lgfortran
```

Comment: I'm building my application in windows with Qt. Adding `win32: LIBS += -lgfortran` to `.pro` file fixed my problem. I'm using MinGW compiler.